# JWPlayer with fast-forward and rewind buttons in android

Tags: jwplayer, forward, rewind

I am using jwplayer in android project.Now the requirement states that the player should have "Fast-FORWARD" and "REWIND" button .

I have looked at the documentation but did not find anything in android sdk.

Answer (score 0):

Then create custom controls and add these two button, and on fastforward with all necessary condition check, just seek the player by 5 or 10 sec     `Player.seek(Player.position+10)` and subtract for backward.